# Probability of next flip being heads given I have seen h heads and t tails

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, likelihood

I am currently attempting to understand "Question 2" at this [link](https://heliosphan.org/estimating-biased-coin.html) but having many difficulties. The problem is as follows:

> A coin has a chance of landing heads with an unknown probability chosen from a [0, 1] uniform random distribution. I then flip this coin and see $h$ heads and $t$ tails in a total of $h + t$ flips. What is the probability that the next flip is a head?

My progress is as follows. Let $p$ denote the bias of the coin, let $S$ denote the event of flipping the coin $h + t$ times and observing $h$ heads and $t$ tails, and let $SH$ denote the event that the next flip is a head. The probability $\Pr(S|p)$ of observing $S$ given bias $p$ is $\binom{h+t}{h}p^h(1-p)^t$ because it is a binomial distribution. Now, we find the marginal probability $\Pr(S)$ as follows

\begin{align}
\Pr(S) &= \int_{0}^1\Pr(S|p) \cdot 1 \enspace dp\\
&= \binom{h+t}{h}\int_0^1 p^h(1-p)^t \enspace dp\\
&= \binom{h+t}{h}\frac{h!t!}{(h+t+1)!}\\
&= \frac{1}{h + t + 1}
\end{align}
where second to last equality follows from a property of the beta function. Then, by Bayes' rule we have
\begin{align}
\Pr(SH|S) &= \frac{\Pr(S|SH)\Pr(SH)}{\Pr(S)}
\end{align}
We know $\Pr(S|SH)$ is 1 since $S$ must occur if $SH$ occurs. We also know that $\Pr(S) = \frac{1}{h + t + 1}$ and $\Pr(SH) = \frac{1}{h+t+2}$. Then it follows that $\Pr(SH|S) = \frac{h+t+1}{h+t+2}$ which is markedly different from the answer the article gives, which is $\frac{h + 1}{h+t+2}$.

So I realized that the difference between my approach and the article's approach was that the author wrote $\Pr(S|p) = p^h(1-p)^t$ instead of multiplying by a factor of $\binom{h+t}{h}$. They also relate this probability to the likelihood $\mathcal{L}(P|S)$ but I am not sure how this likelihood is used. Isn't $\mathcal{L}(P|S) = p^h(1-p)^t$ only true if $S$ is a *specific* sequence of realizations, but in our case we are saying that we got $h$ heads and $t$ tails in total (not a specific sequence)? They end up integrating the likelihood after this but I am not sure why that is any different from my solution.

I have used other sources and confirmed that the article's final solution is indeed correct but I am still unable to understand what is wrong with my solution and why the article assumes a specific ordering of heads and tails in the calculation of $\Pr(S|p)$. I must be misunderstanding something! Why is their solution correct and why is mine wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Once you assert the coin has a probability $p$ of landing heads, and if you assume (as you implicitly are) that the flips are independent, then the chance of any particular flip landing heads is (obviously!) $p.$ There doesn't seem to be anything to analyze.  The problem is that you haven't stated question 2 correctly, so please fix that up.

Comment: @whuber Sorry about that, I have edited the question to reflect the key idea that the bias is unknown. Please let me know if anything else is incorrect in my statements.

Comment: Please re-check your assertions following "we also know that."  A good discipline is to *justify* every such assertion (at least mentally), preferably by appealing to the basic laws of probability.

Comment: Isn’t this asking for the posterior probability for a $U(0,1)$ prior?

Comment: (I suspect the problem might concern confusing the events "$S$ followed by a head" with "$h+1$ heads and $t$ tails in $h+1+t$ flips."  They're not equivalent!)

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I missed this point whuber, thank you so much. Is this why we must fix $S$ to be a specific sequence so we can force $SH$ to be a heads coming after $S$? Dave, I'm sorry but I have not yet learned Bayesian interpretation so am not yet able to decipher your comment.